# Exception to blocking questions (after too many downvotes) for large research institutions with a shared IP?

Tags: feature-request

When I was new to Stackoverflow I got (deservedly) downvotes to two of my questions (-2 and -1), but all my other questions did not get any. Now when I try to ask a new question I get the following Message:

```
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.
```

I assume that this is not because of the two miserable questions I asked so far (considering the number of downvotes I got they were not that bad I guess) but due to the shared IP-address when using the uni network in the library (where I am at the moment). Since we have about 20.000 students here there are probably always a couple guys that dont follow the rules on Stackoverflow.

A lot of students do programming assignments and other research activities involving programming tasks on campus and I don't think everybody should get punished by not being able to ask questions (which is the case right now) from here. I see the requirement of blocking questions at IP-level to prevent the use of multiple accounts but would you be willing to consider exceptions for big research institutions with a shared IP for most of its members?

I think the damage caused to StackOverflow would be a lot less than  the the benefits for thousends of students being able to ask questions on here. Maybe you could consider some sort of an IP-Whitelist?

Comment: Keep in mind that it's not just one bad apple that would cause this.  There'd need to be a *lot* of bad content coming from that IP (relative to the good content) for this to happen.  And if you, as a single user, are still able to provide positive contributions you won't have a problem.  In effect, being on the network only lowered the bar at which you'd be banned.  Had you made positive, rather than negative, contributions, you wouldn't have been.  The feature is specifically configured to address this case, just in a more sophisticated way than whitelists.

Answer (score 6):

In your case, the question ban isn't due to anything other than your own account. You have four deleted questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501570/whats-a-property-in-xml

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358833/difference-of-xml-schema-languages

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322480/laptop-is-getting-to-hot-after-switching-from-windows-8-to-ubuntu-13-04

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229692/highlighted-source-code-inline-with-latex-minted

Three of them were closed, and three downvoted. This wasn't due to a shared IP.

Comment: the last two questions were moved to another community and were quite valid I think. (At the time I didn't know there was SuperUser and Tex-Latex). They were not deleted because the were miserable.

I understand that the second one was inappropriate here, still I think the first one is perfectly valid. I don't feel one should get banned for asking those by any means.